# umask ignored by Netbeans 8 on linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, file-permissions

My linux umask is 002.

```
$ umask
0002
```

Therefore new files have 664 permissions.

```
$ touch new-file
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david   www-data    0 feb 11 11:37 new-file
```

However if I create a new file from netbeans (right click / New / Empty file) it have 644 permissions.

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 david   www-data    0 feb 11 11:40 netbeans-file
```

Can I configure which permissions have new files created from netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans is probably not a child of the shell where you set the umask. The parent will depend a lot on how you log in, but would often be your desktop manager. Figure out how to fix its configuration. (Not a programming question, really.)

Comment: (Why are you in group `www-data`?)

Comment: I want to have write access to files created by Apache.

Comment: You're right. This is not a programming question. Should I delete this?

Comment: "Tools used for programming" are (somewhat grudgingly) tolerated, so I have not voted to close. I would say just leave it, for now.

Comment: But please accept an answer when you can so that this no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tripleee says Netbeans was not a child of the shell where umask were set.

umask command were at .bashrc which is executed only when a shell window is opened but not on session login.

After moving the umask command to .profile all GUI programs including netbeans take the umask properly.

Comment: I'm on CentOS 7.4 and I don't have a .profile. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: Try to add one with "touch ~/.profile". If you want it system wide put a new file in /etc/profile.d/ . Also, you have some info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36762/where-is-the-system-profile-that-gets-sourced-at-login-on-centos-5-8

Answer (score 0):

`umask` is a mask with it the intended permissions, when creating a file, are mixed. That means that if Netbeans wanted a file with rw-r--r-- and the mask is 002 (means that you want to *remove* writing for others), real protections will be rw-r--r--. The operation behind this is:

```
real_rights = wanted_rights & ~umask
```

An application have preferences about protection over a file it creates, and user have preferences on what he do not want on permissions.